# what is the use of secrets in kubernetes, and what is its purpose?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, devops

I am new to kubernetes and I am not able to understand what is the use of secrets in kubernetes, can anybody tell me why secrets are used and what is the purpose of secrets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Secrets are used to manage sensitive information like database passwords, user credentials, ssl certificates etc.

It would help you decouple the sensitive information from the builds. You can bind the secrets as volume or environment variables in the pod at run time

Comment: I wan't to add that though its intended to manage sensitive configuration, its not secure by default as anyone with access to the cluster can view secrets and only need to decode base64 to access secrets in plain text.

For a more secure configuration, usually a secret management tool is coupled with Kubernetes Secrets to add access control, something like Hashicorp Vault for example is popular

Comment: Yes. You are right. Agree with you. Definitely we can look at vault kind of external service to manage the secrets.

Comment: yes actually I had a doubt if someone has access to a cluster can easily view the secret so what's the point in keeping a secret.
I will look into the Vault service.
Thanks @cousine

Comment: @PEkambaram Thanks for the information I will try your suggestions. :)